# How to Tranpose a List Object Header Row for UserForm drop down?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to pull the column headers from a table to use in a drop down in a userform. The number of columns can change and the table may not always start in first row.

```
Sub DisplayUserFormSplitWb()

UserFormSplitWb.Show

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'The following works
'Dim SplitOptions As Range
'Set SplitOptions = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight))

'BELOW DOES NOT WORK
SplitOptions = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange

SplitWbCol.List = Application.Transpose(SplitOptions.Value)

End Sub

Private Sub BtnOK_Click()

UserFormSplitWb.Hide

Call SplitWbMaster.SplitWbToFiles

End Sub
```

On code line `UserFormSplitWb.Show` I get the following:

> Run-time error '424': Object required

Comment: Don't you need the `Set` keyword on `SplitOptions = ...` ?

Comment: @SmileyFtW I just added `Set` before `SplitOptions` and I am now getting "Run-time error '381': Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index."

Comment: Explicitly use the sheet the list is on. It may be that ActiveSheet is not what you think it is. Also, do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module? You should always have that.

Comment: As a better programming practice don't use the default instance of user forms. Declare a variable as `UserFormSplitWB`, `New` it up and then use that variable as an instance of your user form. `Dim myForm As UserFormSplitWB`; `Set myForm = New UserFormSplitWB`, then `myForm.Show`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 'Set' in line

```
Set SplitOptions = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange
```

or direct

```
SplitWbCol.List = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange.Value)
```